# Can see obscured geometry in orthographic view, while can't see it in perspective

Tags: 3d-view, geometry

For some reason I can see geometry that is supposed to be obscured when im in orthographic view, while in perspective
[image: orthographic view]

Orthographic view^

[image: perspective]

Perspective view^

How do I revert to not seeing obscured geometry in orthographic view? (so it looks like in perspective view)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was with high clip end distance, as it was set to its maximum value.